why can't Tests script import namespace of Runtime script?
Assuming I have declare a Unity asset "HMD", which contains 2 directories, "Scripts" and "Tests".
(This project has been uploaded to https://github.com/hpvdt/HMD-Air/blob/d74eb803f933b6a13de33f89468bc70def1126c9/Assets/HMD/Tests/PickleSuite.cs, to demonstrate the error)
Under "Scripts" I have a class called "Pickle":
namespace HMD.Scripts.Pickle
{
    using YamlDotNet.Serialization;
    using YamlDotNet.Serialization.NamingConventions;

    public class Yaml
    {

Under "Tests" I have a testing class called "PickeSuite":
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace HMD.Tests
{
    using Scripts.Pickle;
    using Scripts.Streaming.VCap;

    public class PickeSuite
    {
        // A Test behaves as an ordinary method
        [Test]
        public void PickeSuiteSimplePasses()
        {
...

Upon compilation, it is reported that all namespaces under Scripts cannot be found:
1>PickleSuite.cs(5,11): Error CS0246 : The type or namespace name 'Scripts' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>PickleSuite.cs(6,11): Error CS0246 : The type or namespace name 'Scripts' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


what's the cause of this? How to make the namespace visible?
UPDATE 1: I later opened an open-sourced example to fully understand the design of Unity testing framework:
https://github.com/nowsprinting/UnityTestExamples
When the project is fully loaded in the IDE I can immediately see the difference in namespace organisation: namely, C# compiler automatically recognise the following 4 directories under an asset as source root:

Scripts/Editor
Scripts/Runtime
Tests/Editor
Tests/Runtime


In this case, all namespaces under Scripts can work properly. How to reproduce it in any project with the exact same editor & IDE?
(I can't find any option to do the same in my IDE)


In short - you need to add the reference to the assembly that contains the code you want to be able to test. You cannot link Unity's "default" assembly; you need to place your code in a separate assembly and link it. Then, you'll be able to run your tests.
In unity, assemblies are managed using assembly definitions. You can see them in screenshots of projects that work (*.asmdef files). You can create an assembly definition in the unity editor from the context menu in the Project window.
You can find more details here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html

thanks a lot, why can't I link to Unity's "default"? What makes it special?

You need to set the direct link in your test assembly. And there is no "default" assembly in the project folder to link it.

there should be a "root assembly" that include all assets & has reference to every Unity package (which Unity used to compile executable). If not, there should be a way to generate asmdef automatically

theoretically there is nothing preventing me from loading test runner in production asset, which is only excluded by conditional compilation directives, I just wonder why nobody used it
